# Search array of symbols - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, symbols

Given an array of symbols, how would you iterate over the array, and store the array indexes of matching pairs?

```
foo = [:date, :recorded_at, :scheduled_for, :amount, :activity, :pending ]
```

For example, if you searched for 'recorded_at' and 'activity', it should return `[1,4]`

I thought something like this would work:

```
bar = ['recorded_at','activity']
buzz = bar.each{|i| foo.index(i.to_sym)}
```

However this just returns the strings, `["foo", "bar"]`, not the actual array indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of `Array#each`:

```
buzz = bar.map{|i| foo.index(i.to_sym)}
#=> [1, 4]
```

Comment: ni zen me ke yi yong zhong wen ne

Comment: hao de, wo xia ci yong pinyin!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way, particularly if you have to do this multiple times, for different values of `bar`, or if the arrays are large, would be to first convert `foo` to a hash:

```
foo = [:date, :recorded_at, :scheduled_for, :amount, :activity, :pending ]

foo_hash = Hash[foo.map(&:to_s).zip([*0...foo.size]).to_h]
  #=> {"date"=>0, "recorded_at"=>1, "scheduled_for"=>2,
  #    "amount"=>3, "activity"=>4, "pending"=>5}
```

Then it is a simple hash lookup for any value of `bar`:

```
bar = ['recorded_at','activity']
foo_hash.values_at(*bar)
  #=> [1, 4]
```

For Ruby 1.9+ `Hash[arr]` can be replaced by `arr.to_h`.

If `n=foo.size` and `m=bar.size`, only `m` hash lookups would be required after constructing the hash.  By constrast, for each element of `bar`, there would be, on average, `n/2` comparisons to find the index of an element of `foo` that matches the element of `bar`, for a total of `m*n/2` comparisons.